# Make a Strong Wordlist white special character with python

Tags: list, passwords, word-list

I wanted to make a password list For Brute Forceand  . I need your help.

An 8-digit password list where the characters 4, 8 and (p or P) should be used, and it consists only of numbers and lowercase and uppercase characters, and there are no special characters in it. Thanks for your advice on what software to use in Python and Windows to create this password list. tanks

I still haven't found a way to use special characters for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is by using rstr. rstr is a helper module for easily generating random strings of various types. To use this module, start by [installing it](https://pypi.org/project/rstr/). cd into your project directory and run `pip install rstr`
Then enter and run the following codes in your favourite text editor:

```
from rstr import Rstr
from random import SystemRandom

rs = Rstr(SystemRandom())
result = rs.xeger(r'\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w')
print(rs.rstr(result, 8, include = ['4','8','P']))
```

This will generate and print an 8-digit alphanumeric password including 4, 8 and P. Sample outputs: `7P4Kr7p8`, `qP8P4f7f`